# Bar Charts out of JMH-Data

Tags: bar-chart, charts, error-bars

I want to do some bar charts out of a benchmark I've done with the Java Microbenchmarking Harness.
The simple bar chart isnt the problem but on top of each of the bars, I want to show the variation (error) like on this picture from JMH Viewer.
[image]
Thanks already in advance!

Comment: Welcome to TSE. What did you try?

Comment: Hey, thanks! Nothing yet but a small google search showed that the bar-chart itself is fairly simple but I havent found anything about the error at all which kind of looks like that. :)

Comment: Have a look at sections **4.5.4 Bar Plots** and **4.12 Error Bars** in the [pgfplots manual](https://ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots).

Comment: Thats a good one, thanks!